# PHP form error issue

Tags: php, forms, validation

There is probably a simple solution for this but i'm not very proficient in php! Basically I want to submit a form and the user be returned with a thank you overlay image without refresh. I've managed to get this to work BUT now the form validating isn't working properly...

I need to make my overlay only appear after the form validating is successful, if it isn't successful I need to display the error instead of the thank you overlay...

I know I could use ajax for this form but I don't want to rely on javascript!

At the minute the validating is working, but the image is being overlayed on top of it...

This is php code:

```
<?php
if($_POST['formSubmit'] == "Submit")
{
    $errorMessage = "";

  if(empty($_POST['formName']))
  {
    $errorMessage .= "<li>You forgot to enter your name</li>";
  }
  if(empty($_POST['formTown']))
  {
    $errorMessage .= "<li>You forgot to enter your town</li>";
  }

    $varName = $_POST['formName'];
    $varTown = $_POST['formTown'];
    $varAge = $_POST['formAge'];
    $varEmail = $_POST['formEmail'];

    $varOne = $_POST['hidden-one'];
    $varTwo = $_POST['hidden-two'];
    $varThree = $_POST['hidden-three'];
    $varFour = $_POST['hidden-four'];
    $varFive = $_POST['hidden-five'];

    if(empty($errorMessage)) 
    {
        $fs = fopen("mydata.csv","a");
        fwrite($fs,"\n" . $varName . ", " . $varTown . ", " . $varAge . ", " . $varEmail . ", " . $varOne . $varTwo . $varThree . $varFour . $varFive);
        fclose($fs);
    }
}
?>
```

This is my html (with the php code):

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['formSubmit'])) { 
    print "<div class=\"thank-you\"><a href='enter.php'><img src='images/thankyou-overlay.png'/></a></div>\n"; 
} 
?>

<div id="mainContainer">
<p>Just complete your entry details below.</p>

<?php
if(!empty($errorMessage)) {
    echo("<p>There was an error with your form:</p>\n");
    echo("<ul>" . $errorMessage . "</ul>\n");
} 
?>

<form action="<? echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" target="_self">
    <div class="inputContainer">
    <label class="text" name="name">Full Name:</label>
    <input type="text" class="box" name="formName" value="<?=$varName;?>">
    </div>
        ... more html inputs...
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever you are going to do, you have to use Javascript. You can choose AJAX either using an iframe where you direct your post to, and reading it in a javascript to check status of posting.

Edit:

Like this you can post it:

```
<form action="do_stuff.aspx" method="post" target="my_iframe">
  <input type="submit" value="Do Stuff!" />
</form>

<!-- when the form is submitted, the server response will appear in this iframe -->
<iframe name="my_iframe" src="not_submitted_yet.aspx"></iframe>
```

So after the post, you have to read status from this iframe, (in other words de HTML output from it).

Comment: Having a little trouble understanding this. Could you elaborate a little more about what should go on the do_stuff.aspx and not_submitted_yet.aspx pages.

Comment: Well basically, when you put a iframe in your page, you can make your form post in this iframe (so that the main page won't reload). So with my example, page do_stuff.aspx with the post data will be called but in a iframe!

Answer (score -1):

First , i am having difficulty comprehending what you are trying to do : But still i can point out a few things that have better alternates ;
You should put this code

if($_POST['formSubmit'] == "Submit")
{
   ...

```
}
```

above the form for the functionality you want
and also the above if should have an else to show the form when there are errors.
like
else
{
---form---
}

try this and c if it helps

Comment: He doesn't want his whole page to refresh ;)

Comment: and he does not wanna use ajax 2 ... there is no way he is gonna do the task without refreshing ... at some poit  he might be doing it without knowing

Comment: So with my awnser he should find what he is looking for :)

Comment: sorry i didnt see that ... sure he does find the answer ... simlpe enough ;)